# Difference between wine and wine-devel?

Tags: wine

I want to know the difference between wine and wine-devel, while I couldn't find any info about wine-devel.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`wine-devel` contains applications, scripts, header files, and libraries for [building applications that use wine and/or winelib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2617468/are-there-any-way-to-link-my-program-with-wine-compiled-part/2617558#2617558).

Comment: So wine-devil also contains all the functionality of wine?

Comment: No. `wine` contains wine.